# What forecast method is correct to apply to data in range -1 to 1

Tags: forecasting

I have metrological data they strictly have range -1 to 1. For example

```
-0,97654
0,0376544
0,049765976
-0,578
```

measurement values are tied to a point in time .Example

```
Date    metr
9.27.2019 0:00:00   -0.97654
9.27.2019 1:00:00       0.0376544
9.27.2019 2:00:00       0.049765976
9.27.2019 3:00:00       -0.578
9.27.2019 4:00:00   0.045687
9.28.2019 5:00:00   -0.045688
```

I need to forecast the value by next 24 hours. Arima model doesn't work for me.
because it is decimal fractions in a certain range from -1 to 1

What i should apply method to work  to value with such specific. (ideally in R language)

Comment: Is it possible for values to be exactly -1 or +1? More details about the nature of the measurements would help, as would an example plot of values over time or a larger sample of data. From what you show the values seem to jump around a lot, making me wonder whether forecasting will be reliable. Might the underlying process be changing faster than the 1-hour spacings of your measurements?

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean about ARIMA not working but you could multiply by 100 to avoid the decimal less than 1 issue.

Comment: See https://otexts.com/fpp2/limits.html